# pip `ResolutionError` when installing requirements from file to duplicate a virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm trying to create a duplicate of a python virtualenv on my local machine. I ran `pip freeze > requirements.txt` within my existing virtualenv, then deactivated it before creating and activating a brand new virtualenv with the exact same python version (3.8.10). I then ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` to add all the packages I need but it fails with this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 31), -r requirements.txt (line 40), -r requirements.txt (line 48) and Jinja2==2.11.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested Jinja2==2.11.3
    cookiecutter 2.1.1 depends on Jinja2<4.0.0 and >=2.7
    distributed 2022.8.0 depends on jinja2
    flask 2.2.2 depends on Jinja2>=3.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

I'm struggling to understand how this can be as all of these packages are installed together in my original virtualenv, so the requirements must be resolved there. Also, I tried removing that `Jinja2` package from the `requirements.txt` file just in case there was something weird about that but then it just complains about other packages.

Can anyone explain to me why I see this behaviour and what I could try to resolve it?

Comment: Just remove the version specifier from Jinja2. The current version (3.1.2) will satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: I've tried that, it just raises the same error about other packages

Comment: Can you resolve them the same way?